# Use a different URL path / permalink for CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting

I just need some advice.

My permalink is currently set to `Post name` and everything is working fine. However, I will need to start using a custom structure for the default post type and change to `/%category%/%postname%/`. Not a problem and most are working. However, one of my CPT where I remove the permalink is causing an issue.

The CPT called `landing` and I remove the permalink using the code below.

```
function custom_remove_cpt_slug( $post_link, $post, $leavename ) {

    if ( 'landing' != $post->post_type || 'publish' != $post->post_status ) {
        return $post_link;
    }

    $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link );

    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'custom_remove_cpt_slug', 10, 3 );
```

Is there a way to prevent the CPT from using the custom structure? I also did try

`'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'landing', 'with_front' => false )`

Manually entering the slug definitely works `(i.e.)https://example.com/landing/abc`

Comment: As you've stated it yourself, "*custom structure for the default post type*", so your CPT will supposedly not gonna be using that custom structure (`/%category%/%postname%/`). And what you are trying to achieve is for your CPT posts to have no rewrite base, right? I.e. Their URL would be `example.com/landing-post` and not `example.com/landing/landing-post` (the latter uses `landing` as the rewrite base) ? If so, then they will conflict with Pages (post type `page`) - e.g. `example.com/landing-post` might be seen by WordPress as a post in your CPT, or as a Page. Were you aware of that issue?

Comment: Hi and thanks for responding.

(1). Doesn't all CPT use the same structure located in `options-permalink.php`? (2) Yes, the CPT will have no rewrite base making it appear like a `page`. (3). I just did a test and you're correct, it's going to conflict with pages if the `url` are the same and load the pages as a priority. Not a problem though as we'll keep an eye out for it.

Comment: (1) No. But if your permalink structure there (for the default `post` type) contains a "front" (i.e. static string/text) like "blog" as in `/blog/%postname%/`, then that `/blog/` will be used for CPT too unless the `with_front` is `false`. (2) OK. (3) If so, what is the problem you're having then?